# Why does the default arrow cursor does not change when I change my X11 cursor theme?

Tags: 11.10, customization, cursor

Using the Advance Settings utility from the Ubuntu Software Center I can change the X11 cursor theme, but the only cursor that *does not* change is the default arrow cursor. How can I get it to change too?

Comment: Did you log out an back in ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, since then I have logged out and restarted the computer.

Comment: try `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`

Comment: `update-alternatives` does not see any of the themes I manually dropped into `/usr/share/icons`. How do I regenerate the list?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,